# Track rows movement in QTableView from model

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, qt5, pyside2

TLDR: How to inform model about order of rows in view (and that it changed)?

So I've got my model that inherits form `QAbstractTableModel` and I'm presenting it using subclassed `QTableView` where I set vertical header to be movable, so I can drag and drop rows with mouse by grabbing side of table. It works great, but I want to let my model know in order rows are in.

I've found `sectionMoved` signal, but it's emitted only once, i.e. when I've moved row 0 to 1, I only get informed that row's 0 visual index changed from 0 to 1; I don't get information that also (logical) row 1 visual index changed from 1 to 0 to accommodate that first change.

So how should I pass information about order in which items are displayed to my model? Or the only thing I can do is iterate over all rows after change has happened (in slot connected to sectionMoved signal) check their visual index and pass it to model? Is there a better pattern how such  cases should be handled?

I've also tried reimplementing `dragEnterEvent` and `dropEvent` and calling `moveRow` on drop, but signal/slot mechanism seems more qt-way and is more testable; also I don't really need to move rows in model, I only need order to save it for next program execution.

If it meters I use pyside2 (Qt for python) based on Qt 5.14 and python 3.8; but I think my question is more about general Qt approach.

Comment: Those are *not* changes in the model, the section movement is only for appearance, the model is *not* changed (nor it should!), and the logical indexes are always kept. If you want to change the model accordingly, you need to implement that using [`beginMoveRows()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#beginMoveRows) and the related `endMoveRows`, `beginMoveColumns` and `endMoveColumns`.

Comment: @musicamante - yes, exactly! Plese see my updated question. I just want to preserve view's order for next session, so i need to store this order somehow somewhere. I've already tried move-rows route, but it's overkill IMHO :)

Comment: I'd say you've answered your own question: store the visual indexes and then restore it on the next session. You'll have to find a good method to do that, with correctly ordered calls to [`moveSection()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qheaderview.html#moveSection); once you find a good approach, I'd suggest you to add your own answer.

Comment: I think the information you need to save/restore can be gleaned from the [`QHeaderView`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qheaderview.html#saveState).